# Need help to implement two different areas (colors) in my footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to split up my footer, so one part is a color and another part of the footer is another color. I'm using bootstrap and have tried with rows inside my footer. Don't think its logical to use the footer tag twice.

Want my footer to be split like in this images. 
[image]

**Some code i have done so far:**

```
<!-- Foooter
================== -->
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Contact us form -->
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="headline">
                        <h3>Text here</h3>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="content">
                        <p>
                            Text here
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Go social -->
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="headline">
                        <h3>Text here</h3>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="content">
                        <p>
                            Text here
                        </p>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-vk"></i></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Subscibe -->
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="headline">
                        <h3>Text here</h3>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="content">
                        <p>
                            Text here
                        </p>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" Width="150px" CssClass="form-control" />
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <button runat="server" type="submit" class="my-btn">OK</button>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="lastcontent">
                         <p>&copy; Text here 2015. <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="#">Terms of Service</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In my Css file i have made this line:

```
.lastcontent p {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

This makes it blue, but it is not 100% in width.

As you can see, I have made another row in the footer at the bottom, but this doesn't work.. Is there anything else i should do in order to accomplish this footer with two colors?

Comment: does this work? http://codepen.io/tylerism/pen/wapWQp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you use like this?

```css
body {margin: 0;}
.primary {background-color: #00f; color: #fff;}
.secondary {background-color: #99f; color: #000;}
p {margin: 0; font: 10pt verdana; padding: 15px; text-align: center;}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="primary">
    <p>This is a single Footer tag!</p>
    <p>You can use bootstrap's <code>.col-md-4</code> for a three column one.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="secondary">
    <p>This is a different colour Footer</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```